# Connecting to own PC using public IP

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm having a problem with sockets.
I've written myself two simple applications, one server and one client.
The server simply waits for a UDP packet to arrive, printing out something in the console once that happens.
The client sends a UDP packet to a specific end point.

```
// server
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
sock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 1337));
IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
sock.ReceiveFrom(buf, ref remote);
Console.WriteLine("Received packet.");

// client
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Console.ReadLine()), UInt16.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
byte[] buf = { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; // random data
sock.SendTo(buf, remote);
```

Now the weird thing is that when the client socket sends its packet to the public IP address of my router, the server socket only receives it if the client is not run on the same PC as the server. So if I start the server on my PC and then start the client on my PC, enter my public IP and port 1337, the server doesn't receive anything.
However, if I send the client application to my friend and give him my IP address and port, it works perfectly fine.
It also works if I let the client connect to my local IP instead of my public one.

Am I the only one experiencing this behaviour?
Port 1337 is forwarded to the computer the server is ran on, btw.

Comment: This is normal.  Most NAT routers only do port-forwarding for connections coming in from the WAN, not the LAN.  If there's any workaround, it would depend on the model of your NAT router, and would be off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most routers and modems do not normally forward UDP traffic -- see http://www.gotroot.com/blogpost4-Why-your-should-never-forward-UDP-out-of-your-firewall for an explanation.  Also try attaching both the client and server to the same physical network (well, subnet) and to try sending datagrams directly to the server instead of forwarding them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just being curious, your link describes UDP hole punching, doesn't it?

Comment: the OP says that he is able to receive UDP packet from the public internet to his internal LAN connected PC through his router. So your answer that routers don't normally forward UDP traffic, in this case, is wrong!

Comment: @user1046192: Yes, it does.  It's also the technique used by a number of applications (including Skype, IIRC) to allow direct end-to-end communications through NAT and firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a NAT configuration issue. You must have configured nat on the router to forward packets coming on the public interface with specific port (1337) to be forwarded to the server. So this works when your friend sends you a UDP packet.

But you must not (don't know if its even possible) have configured natting the other way around meaning the same UDP packet coming to the internal interface. This is the case when you send packet from server to client with both on the same machine.

When both the server and client (on a single machine or two different machines) are on your internal network it will be best to use the server's interface id than depending on natting